# Correct File/Dir Permissions for Wordpress on CentOS

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache

I am looking for the correct way to set up permissions on files and directories so that FTP user can update the files while HTTPD process can read/write everything inside wp-content.
Basically, we need to add apache user to USER group and vise-versa then set 664 and 775 on files/dirs and that will work.
The problem is with files being uploaded via FTP gets 644 and ownership by USER while files created by apache will have ownership of apache.

Could be great if someone can help here based on experience and tests and not only on guessing.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for the correct way to set up permissions on files and directories so that FTP user can update the files while HTTPD process can read/write everything inside wp-content

all file folders need to be "0755"
all files need to be "0644"